# SMTPlib doesn't work the moment I implement classes (Python)

Tags: python, smtplib, python-class

I am using code from the link https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/
It worked perfectly. I have attached the code for reference (1st code). But, then I tried to put most of the code inside a class (2nd code). The mail is still sent. But, now it has no subject, and most of the body is gone. It is being sent to an absurd address. But, the bcc for some strange reason, includes the correct email address. I have attached the screenshot of the email below. I am a newbie in python, so I don't know where I went wrong.

```
import smtplib

gmail_user = 'you@gmail.com'
gmail_password = 'P@ssword!'

sent_from = gmail_user
to = ['me@gmail.com', 'bill@gmail.com']
subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'
body = 'Hey, what is up?\n\n- You'

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print 'Email sent!'
except:
    print 'Something went wrong...'
```

```
    import smtplib
    class emailInfo:
        user='Y@gmail.com'
        password = 'XXXX'
        sent_from = user
        to = []
        subject =''
        body =''
        email_text=''
        def createEmailText(self):
            return """\
            From: %s
            To: %s
            Subject: %s
            %s
            """ % (self.sent_from, ", ".join(self.to), self.subject, self.body)
        def send_email(self):
            server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(self.user, self.password)
            server.sendmail(self.sent_from, self.to, self.email_text)
            server.close()

    try:
        myEmail=emailInfo()
        myEmail.body='Hey, what is up buddy?\n\n- You'
        myEmail.subject='OMG Super Important Message 2'
        myEmail.to=['Z@gmail.com']
        myEmail.email_text=myEmail.createEmailText()
        myEmail.send_email()
        print('Email sent!')
    except:
        print('Something went wrong...')
```

[Incorrect email screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHRXg.png)

Comment: use your email in "to" to see what happens...it can be gmail security you don't know

Comment: Thanks ,user1438644. I used my email address. I fixed the security issues, I think it is an issue with the texts getting jumbled up when I put it in a class.

Comment: good I'happy for you

Comment: Did I implement the classes incorrectly?

Comment: hm user, password, sent_from, to, subject, body and email_text should be variable of instance not of class like you declare them. define 'def __init__(self)' and self.to etc but the logic is correct. You fixed the error right?

Comment: I fixed it just now, the problem was with the email_text assignment. I had to remove the indentation for the string. That was causing problems. Removing it fixed everything. Also, thanks @user1438644, I will look into python classes. I love this community!